# Add mutex to struct to allow locking it when doing certain operations

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a list of objects that are generated using a library and allow some complex operations. Since these operations take so long my goal is to multi-thread them but I am running into the problem that these objects are used multiple times and it isn't thread safe. To explain it better what I am trying to multi-thread:

Task 1 needs object with id 5
Task 2 needs object with id 2
Task 3 needs object with id 12
Task 4 needs object with id 5
...

The problem arises in this example when a task calculated that it needs an object with an id that is already being used like here with task 1 and 4. These objects are all in a vector and my idea was to put them in a struct that has a mutex like so:

```cpp
struct struct_with_lock{
    object_from_library id;
    std::mutex lock;
};
```

Now when doing a specific operation with the object I want it to check for the mutex and then lock/unlock however required. I am stuck at how I would initialize this struct (do I need to create a list of mutexes and assign them to the structs?) and if this is even a smart idea. Any help would be appreciated! And of course if I didn't make anything clear please tell me.

Comment: You didn't make anything clear. Normally you put the mutex together with the resource that you want to synchronize access to. When you use it, lock the mutex. When you're done, unlock it. What part are you having issues with?

Comment: I want to synchronize access to the objects from the library. What I am having trouble with is how to set up and initialize the struct to allow me to do so.

Comment: https://drodil.medium.com/the-object-pool-pattern-e424507b996a

Comment: there is a risk of starvation in the way you think about this, imagine you lock object 5 in task 1 and object 5 is not unlocked until task 1 is done, so task 4 is waiting but then task 1 acquires the object again... what is preventing task 1 from acquiring it again before task 4 ?

Comment: @rustyx thanks currently trying to implement it with the help of that.

Comment: @AndersK the task is done after it used the object so there wouldn't be a problem of it reacquiring the object. The amount of tasks are finite so my idea was that at some point every task got their object.